# DAX split a column string into a list and search split values in another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have DAX measure which gives list of all selected values in a slicer seperated by comma

```
Measure =CONCATENATEX(VALUES ( Table[value] ) , [value] , ",")
```

Measure values are like : ABC,CDEF,EFG

Now there is a table2 which contains following data:

Table2:

```
Col1 Col2
200  ABC,GHJ,NKUL
300  BPO,CDEF, MNO
500  A
```

Now I have to create a DAX measure to count rows in Table2 which contains any of split values.
Here row1 and row2 satisfies condition as they contains ABC and CDEF respectively.

Tried with generate list solution but didn't work properly with string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just count rows that contain a comma:

```
CountSplits =
COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( Table2, CONTAINSSTRING ( Table2[Col2], "," ) ) )
```

Comment: I think you didnt get my question. I didnt need to count splits!

Comment: Perhaps you can reword it to be more clear what you do want to be counted then.